# Having an issue learning constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Ok so here is my XML for my activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.xxx.listview.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_listview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/main_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"></ListView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the view which I end up with.

[image: What the look looks like when rendered in the emulator.]

Just learning so I'm new to the constraints thing. They work a bit differently from my iOS life and trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you got errors. I saw few issues with your layout:

1. You're missing `constraintTop` of your `ListView` --> your `ListView` will become `wrap_content` height and align bottom.
2. You tell your `ToolBar` `constraintTop` to `Parent` and `constraintBottom` to `ListView` --> that's the reason why your `ToolBar` is in the middle of top `ListView` and top `Parent`.

To solve your issue, just remove the `constraintBottom` of your `toolBar` and add `constraintTop` of `ListView` to bottom of toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ListView` is missing a constraint on its top:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
```

The layout tooling should be displaying a warning somewhere telling you it will be repositioned or will be the wrong size because your height is 0dp. It will be telling you to add another constraint.

If your height is 0 then you need a constraint on the top and bottom of the view. If your width is 0 you need a constraint on the left and right of the view.

Answer (score 0):

- try this (by using Constraint bear in mind we've `4-constraints` `top,bottom,left and Right`)
- we have to use like that

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/cl_layout"
tools:context="com.example.xxx.listview.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_listview"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/main_listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"></ListView>
```

Comment: You forgot your top constraint in the ListView